# How to embed text field into UI Collection View cells and store the text into an array?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios7, uicollectionview

I'm new to Swift and have no prior experience with Objective C. I usually implement an UI Collection View like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

let reuseIdentifier = "cell" 
var items = ["1", "2", "3" ... "100"]


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
   }
}
```

But I do not have the slightest idea of how to have a text field in those cells rather than the numbers from declared array (items). And how would I be able to store the text entered into an array?

P.S Im not posting this expecting for a code (although it would help me a lot) but rather for some guidance or weblinks on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. A simple way might be to:

drag a UITextView into your UICollectionView prototype cell in your storyboard
give the textView a tag number so you can reference it in code
in the function `didSelectItemAtIndexPath, you need to get a reference to the cell, like this:

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

then you can get a reference to the UITextView by tag like this

```
let textField = cell?.viewWtihTag(100) as? UITextField
```

Now you can do whatever you want with the value.  The issue here is when a user clicks in the UITextField, it will not trigger this method (although they can edit the textField).  If they make a change and then click outside the textField, it will trigger this method, and you will see the changed text.  You can work around this by adding a checkbox or something for the user to accept their changes. or something like that.